# сигналы частично не доходят до приложения(демона)

Tags: linux, c, signal

В рамках одного курса написал приложение, которое при отправке ему сигнала SIGTERM выдает в вывод количество присланных сигналов SIGUSR1 и SIGUSR2 
Написал программу, которая по pid шлет эти сигналы 
код основной программы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int signal_cntr1 = 0;
int signal_cntr2 = 0;



void sig_handler1(int unused){
    signal_cntr1++;
}

void sig_handler2(int unused){
    signal_cntr2++;
}

void sig_handler3(int unused){
    printf("%d %d\n",signal_cntr1, signal_cntr2);
    exit(0);
}





int main(){
    signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler1);
    signal(SIGUSR2, sig_handler2);
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler3);
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

код тестовой программы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>





int main(int v, char **c){
    int i;
    if(v != 2){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 253; i++){
        kill(atoi(c[1]), SIGUSR1);
        usleep(5000);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 124; i++){
        kill(atoi(c[1]), SIGUSR2);
        usleep(5000);
    }
    kill(atoi(c[1]), SIGTERM);
    usleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

но работа получается такая

```
brainiac@brainiac-Latitude-7480:~/workspace/linux_fund$ ./solution &
[3] 4542
[2]   Done                    ./solution
brainiac@brainiac-Latitude-7480:~/workspace/linux_fund$ ./a.out 4542
78 40
[3]-  Done                    ./solution
brainiac@brainiac-Latitude-7480:~/workspace/linux_fund$
```

хотя в приложении проверки отправляется 253 сигнала sigusr1 и 124 сигнала sigusr2, а приложение показывает 78 и 40 соответственно.
Где я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обычном люнихе сигналы НЕ буферируются. Это означает, что если процесс не успел обработать один сигнал, а пришёл воторой, того же типа, то он будет потерян. Похоже, именно это у Вас и происходит.

Сигнал отправляются с периодом всего 5 мсек, а с учётом того, что процессор у Вас загружен на 100% оператором *while(1);*, я вполне допускаю потерю сигналов.

Что бы этого не происходило, можно воспользоваться расширениями RT Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Сигналы одинакового типа в Linux не становятся в очередь. Если процесс сейчас обрабатывает `SIGUSR1` и прилетает другой `SIGUSR1`, то он просто игнорируется. А вот если обрабатывается `SIGUSR1` и прилетает `SIGUSR2`, то вот тогда обработаны будут оба.

Полагаю, если поднять задержки между посылкой сигналов, то проблема на конкретной системе в конкретный момент времени может стать менее заметной или исчезнуть (если каждый сигнал будет успевать обрабатываться до следующего сигнала). А если опустить задержки или убрать полностью — наоборот, станет более ярко выраженной.